# Accented characters not displying correctly in the HTML Razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mustache

I've a drop-down list with a default value in french "Sélectionnez le type de client" (select customer type). When i debug it, i don't see any issue in the code behind, however when it gets displayed in the HTML page, it's displayed as "s&#233;lectionnez le type de client"

I tried to add the meta tag characterset "UTF-8, printing it as a HTML Raw (@HTML.Raw(Model.SelectCustomerType)) but nothing works. Below is the code snippet.

```
    model.selectCustomerType = HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(customerTypedefaultvalue);
```

```
<script>
    var defaultCustomerType = "@Model.SelectCustomerType";
</script>

<script type="mustache/x-tmpl">
    <option value="">{{Model.selectCustomerType}}</option>
   </script>
```

How do i correctly print the accented characters?

Comment: try setting lang attribute to "fr"

Comment: It is a generic website and the language attribute gets set automatically by language.